# How to Deploy VMs on Ubuntu Server

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, virtualization, remote-access

I currently created a server with Ubuntu 16.04 and created one Virtual Machine that I want 4-5 people to use simultaneously, however I hit a snag and can't seem to find an answer for it. How do I deploy the VM and connect to it using windows mac or another linux computer?

Comment: Your question is too broad. Fire up your vm (what technology?? KVM, docker, vbox, vmware ? command line or grahpical?) and connect (ssh, ftp, vnc, http, samba ????)

Comment: @Panther I am currently running LXDE on Ubuntu server with KVM and Virtual Machine Manager that I would like to use vnc to have at least 4-5 computers connected to 4-5 user accounts at the same time. The hardware isn't an issue. Just the deploying and connecting is the snag.

Comment: My advice is to use spice. It is built into KVM and you connect via the spice client, which runs on any OS. IMHO spice is the fastest "vnc client" to connect to KVM guests. See https://spice-space.org/ Spice is fairly mature at this point and for the most part works out of the box, most of the tutorials are old. https://velenux.wordpress.com/2016/12/30/how-to-install-and-use-spice-for-vms-in-debian-ubuntu-or-mint/

Comment: See also https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_16.04&p=kvm&f=10